# Redirect for single page with htaccess file not working when url has spaces

Tags: 6, redirection

Im trying to add a redirect to my site from one page to annother using the .htaccess file. From the documentation at http://drupal.org/node/38960 I tried the following but it doesnt appear to do anything. Thanks

```
# RewriteBase /


#custom redirects (this is where the code ive added begins) 

RewriteRule http://mysite.com/one http://mysite.com/two [R=301,L]

#end custom redirects (this is where the code ive added ends)


# Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Let the redirect module do it for you... http://drupal.org/project/redirect

Comment: The module works when I do a test and redirect from mysite.com/a to mysite.com/b (neither are real pages). However it doenst work when I try to override a taxonomy path which what i need to do. Thanks

Comment: Incase its of interest the path is: taxonomy/term/6%207%208%209

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the issue was spaces in the url. Working with this:

```
# RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^taxonomy\/term\/6\ 7\ 8\ 9$ /taxonomy/term/all [L,R=301]
```